# Integrating external application into SalesForce frontend

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I would like to create a component that will integrate an external javascript application into SalesForce. This means, that the application will start and run in the SalesForce. This application needs access to whole DOM for searching for elements and reading the dimensions of arbitrary elements on the screen. I created a prototype - a LWC that has a script uploaded as a static resource. This script creates a new script element with src set to the URI of external applications script. Now the "src" is changed to "data-locker-src", the script is fetched as XHR and then ran. My problem is that the HTML elements of SalesForce seem to be invisible to the external app. I suppose this is because of the DOM access containment "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm" policy. My questions are

- Is it even possible to achieve what I need in SalesForce?
- If yes, is my approach a way to go, or do I need to do it differently?
- Is it possible to somehow make this included everywhere in a SF applicaiton without manually needing to add the LWC to every page?

UPDATE: this is the description of what I need to integrate

I am building a small annotation app. On a webpage where this is integrated, users can select an html element and enter an annotation - this can later be shown - the element is highlighted and the annotation text displayed next to it. So, I want to send only the element's selector and the text to the REST api. Then later I want to fetch these, find the element, find its position and size and draw a yellow highligh on top of it so users can easily see what the annotation text is about.

Comment: Is this external application running queries and DML against an external database as well as Salesforce? Does this external application have its own authentication etc. and users access them for other purposes?

Comment: No, it only uses an external REST api. It does not need to interact with salesforce in any other way than accessing the DOM on the frontend.

Comment: LWC component cannot access elements outside its scope (check this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_locker_dom). Also, Lightning framework itself access cloned copies of window, document etc (check this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_locker_global_access). That being said, I don't think you can use secure wrapped elements in your code and its something lightning platform uses internally.

Comment: I suppose you want to be able to send any UI element data on the salesforce page using your LWC component thru an external REST api callout? Also, the static resource that you have added, is that being used to generate the UI elements inside your LWC component? Just curious: Why do you need this on all the pages?

Comment: I think you need the canvas app.

Comment: @arut I am building a small annotation app. On a webpage where this is integrated, users can select an html element and enter an annotation - this can later be shown - the element is highlighted and the annotation text displayed next to it. So, I want to send only the element's selector and the text to the REST api. Then later I want to fetch these, find the element, find its position and size and draw a yellow highligh on top of it so users can easily see what the annotation text is about.

Comment: @rahulgawale thank you this indeed looks good!